# How to resolve null reference exception in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This where i get the null reference exception

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Movie.GenreId, new SelectList(Model.Genres, "Id", "Name"),"Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I Have a `MovieViewModel` through which I passed my genre and movie model before building create logic in my controller and the rendering it to the view

```
 // GET: Movies/Create
                public ActionResult Create()
                {

                    var genres = _DbContext.Genres.ToList();
                    var ViewModel = new MovieViewModel
                    {
                        Genres = genres
                    };
                    return View(ViewModel);
                }

                // POST: Movies/Create

                [HttpPost]
                public ActionResult Create(Movie movie)
                {
                    // TODO: Add insert logic here
                    try
                    {
                        // TODO: Add insert logic here
                        _DbContext.Movies.Add(movie);
                        _DbContext.SaveChanges();

                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return View();
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null Reference exception occurs when a value is assumed to exist, yet, it's `null`. When you build your dropdown list, the elements to appear in that control are assumed to have values for Id and Name, as you have specified. Since that expectation is not fulfilled (a Name is probably null) you get this error. You should use a filter in order to avoid loading a null as Name, or to use a default.